# How to make a copy of a Java class in runtime?

Tags: java, code-generation, bytecode, bytecode-manipulation

I have a class

```
class Foo {
    int increment(int x) {
        return x + 1;
    }
}
```

I want to obtain a copy of this class in runtime, e. g. a class like

```
class Foo$Copy1 {
    int increment(int x) {
        return x + 1;
    }
}
```

Which has all the same methods, but a different name.

[`Proxy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) seem to help with *delegating*, but not *copying* the methods with all their bodies.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Methods do not get instantiated. Are you sure you're talking about a class and not an object?

Comment: The obvious question is: why do you want to do this? You can't convert a class loaded through a standard classloader back into the class file it came from, the best you can do is write your own classloader to intercept calls to `defineClass()`.

Comment: @biziclop I want to keep the profile of each method call within the copied methods clean monomorphic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [Byte Buddy](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy) for this:

```
Class<?> type = new ByteBuddy()
  .redefine(Foo.class)
  .name("Foo$Copy1")
  .make()
  .load(Foo.class.getClassLoader())
  .getLoaded();

Method method = type.getDeclaredMethod("increment", int.class);
int result = (Integer) method.invoke(type.newInstance(), 1);
```

Note that this approach redefines any uses of the class within `Foo`, e.g. if a method returned `Foo`, it would now return `Foo$Copy1`. Same goes for all code-references.

Comment: Thank you. Does it use private ClassLoader's `defineClass()` method for this or goes another way?

Comment: You can choose a `ClassLoadingStrategy` as a second argument. By default, unless the bootstrap class loader is supplied, injection into the class loader of `Foo` is used. With `ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.WRAPPER`, you can also create a throw-away class loader.

Answer (score 2):

@leventov what about this one? https://gist.github.com/serkan-ozal/8737583841b4b12e3a42d39d4af051ae

Comment: Probably this is the right solution for those who already use Javassist. I had no preference between Javassist and Byte Buddy initially

Comment: @leventov in addition, you may also use BCEL from JDK (it comes from JDK but not public API, because it is located under "com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal" package) without being dependent to Javassist.

Comment: like this `
String copyClassName = classToBeCopied.getName() + "$Copy";
ClassGen classGen = new ClassGen(Repository.lookupClass(classToBeCopied));
classGen.setClassName(copyClassName);
byte[] bytecode = classGen.getJavaClass().getBytes();
return UNSAFE.defineClass(
                    copyClassName, 
                    bytecode, 
                    0, 
                    bytecode.length, 
                    classToBeCopied.getClassLoader(), 
                    classToBeCopied.getProtectionDomain());
`

Answer (score 1):

I think using Unsafe could be enough if you have normal access to the bytecode.

Something like `Foo.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()` can give you the bytecode for the class.

Then use 
`sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(String name, byte[] code, int off, int len, ClassLoader classLoader, ProtectionDomain protectionDomain)` to define the class in the same classloader and protection domain as Foo but with a different name.

The details are to figure out, but it might be the simplest approach without any third party libraries.

Comment: Probably the ByteBuddy approach is more flexible and easier to maintain later.

Comment: You would need to redefine the class name in the class file and any self-references, though. Simply using the `Foo`-named class file would not work.