# Byte Buddy: Convert an object of a class from one class loader to same class loaded in another class loader

Tags: byte-buddy

I'm exploring if Byte Buddy is the right tool for me to use. I was looking at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40774770/359455) which talks about how with Byte Buddy, one can take a class `Foo` loaded with class loader `A`, rename it to `Bar` and redefine it on another class loader `B`. That's incredible. 
My question is:

1. Is it possible to have an object which was created from `Foo` on class loader `A` and convert to `Bar`'s object which is coming from class loader `B`? The solution which I have in mind right now is to basically serialize the object from `Foo` and then edit the serialized bytes to rename the name of the class. It would be nice if I can do it safely with Byte Buddy. Another solution would be to use [Transloader](https://code.google.com/archive/p/transloader/).
2. Is java-agent or any special instrumentation required for doing all the things that was described in the above SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40774770/359455)

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always load a class in another class loader without using a Java agent. As for translating the class, replacing the symbol of one class name to anther should not be a problem but you need to watch out for serial version UIDs where there name of the class might be a part of. Byte Buddy is a code generation library and does not add any extra help for such operations.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll watch out for the Serial UID change.